# ASIHTTPRequest Redirect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHTTPRequest in my app to handle Google login in my app.

in one of my requests i get Redirect and this is what i do:

```
- (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request willRedirectToURL:(NSURL *)newURL{
    ASIHTTPRequest *redirect = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:newURL];
    [redirect setTimeOutSeconds:30];
    [redirect setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
    [redirect setDelegate:self]; 
    [redirect startAsynchronous];

    NSLog(@"Redirect - %@",url);
}
```

And when i make this request non of the ASIHTTPRequest delegate methods not called, the is the url that i make the redirect:

```
https://accounts.google.com/Logout2?service=sj&amp;ilo=1&amp;ils=s.IL&amp;ilc=0&amp;continue=http%3A%2F%2Fmusic.google.com%2Fmusic%2Flisten&amp;zx=-834167044
```

Any idea why it happen?

## Edit

The newURL is equal to :

```
https://accounts.google.com/Logout2?service=sj&amp;ilo=1&amp;ils=s.IL&amp;ilc=0&amp;continue=http%3A%2F%2Fmusic.google.com%2Fmusic%2Flisten&amp;zx=835989037
```

but when i try to get the html i get the the redirect url is :

```
https://accounts.google.com/Logout2?service=sj&amp;amp;ilo=1&amp;amp;ils=s.IL&amp;amp;ilc=0&amp;amp;continue=http%3A%2F%2Fmusic.google.com%2Fmusic%2Flisten&amp;amp;zx=835989037
```

And there is diffrent between the two.any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you redirecting with a new `ASIHTTPRequest` when the original request will open the same URL? What happens when you don't redirect with the new request?

I think that you'd better stop the original request and then create the new one.

Comment: I try it and it won't help, and i add more details to my post

Comment: The difference between the two url is that every `&amp;` in newURL is replaced by `&amp;amp;` in the html. You don't answer to my original questions: why do you need to redirect? Do you get some errors or nothing happens after the redirect starts?

Comment: OK, now i understand what you mean, i always though that i need to implement in my self the redirect, when i remove this method it work fine. thx!!